# Alias names to with rollup in SQL queries?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, rollup

I am using `with rollup` in my sql query. I am not getting alias name for rollup.

My SQL is

```
SELECT [Column1],
       sum([Column2])
FROM   Tablea
GROUP  BY [Column2] WITH ROLLUP
```

Which returns

```
s       8
t       8
j       8
null    24
```

How can I replace the `NULL` in the total row?

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [`GROUPING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx) function in a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN GROUPING([Column1]) = 1 THEN 'Total'
         ELSE [Column1]
       END [Column1],
       sum([Column2])
FROM   Tablea
GROUP  BY [Column1] WITH ROLLUP
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21023)

Comment: @Ethan: Questions should be asked in **Questions** rather than Comments; so they can be answered in **Answers** instead of additional Comments.

Answer (score 7):

```
select 
isnull([column1],'rollup'), 
sum([column2] )
from tableA
group by [column1] 
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: This does not return the correct results if `column1` contains `NULL`s. The `GROUPING` function is the correct way. ["GROUPING is used to distinguish the null values that are returned by ROLLUP, CUBE or GROUPING SETS from standard null values."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx)

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT ifnull([column1],'total'),
       sum([Column2])
FROM   Tablea
GROUP  BY [Column2] WITH ROLLUP
```