# Sum rows from different conditions in Mysql

Tags: mysql

The original table is large so I will simplify it:

mytable:

```
CONDITION SIZE 
1          10
9          10
9          10
1          20
9          20
1          20
1          30
```

With a query similar to

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN CONDITION=1 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'BAD' END AS Status,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Small,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Medium,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Large,
FROM mytable GROUP BY Status
```

Then we have this result

```
Status    Small    Medium    Large
OK         1         2         1
BAD        2         1         0
```

What is the proper code to get:

```
Status    Small    Medium    Large
OK         1         2         1
BAD        2         1         0
TOTAL      3         3         1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `WITH ROLLUP` clause to your `GROUP BY` condition like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN CONDITION=1 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'BAD' END AS Status,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Small,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Medium,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Large,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Status WITH ROLLUP
```

This would yield a result set like:

```
Status    Small    Medium    Large
OK         1         2         1
BAD        2         1         0
[NULL]     3         3         1
```

You would need to understand the behavior that there would not be any `Total` value in the Status column. Instead the Status column would have a NULL value indicating that this is where the rollup is made.

For more information you can read the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: I think you can get TOTAL by wrapping the CASE..END in COALESCE(CASE..END, 'ALL) AS Status. Or somersetting like that.

Comment: @KarlKieninger: Not quite, because the query is grouped by the `Status` alias so that's somewhat recursive.  If the `GROUP BY` clause was changed so as not to use the alias, then that would indeed be possible.

Comment: @eggyal right. as an aside, in sql server you could make use of GROUPING to  handle the NULL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897415/alias-names-to-with-rollup-in-sql-queries) but I did not find equivalent in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need union in a total query since you cannot aggregate in different ways at the same time.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN CONDITION=1 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'BAD' END AS Status,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Small,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Medium,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Large,
FROM mytable GROUP BY Status

UNION

SELECT
  'Total' AS Status,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Small,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Medium,
  SUM (CASE WHEN SIZE=30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Large,
FROM mytable
```

Comment: JUST TESTED AND IT WORKED GREATLY! THANK YOU!

Comment: Works, but in essence requires two queries (an approximate doubling of processing effort).

Comment: Hey, I didn't know about roll-up. Look how I just learned something. Not sure how it works internally, but i would expect you are right that it is much better then mine.

Comment: @KarlKieninger Glad to help transfer knowledge.  In a case where you really needed to put `Total` in the Status column and didn't have the ability to use an intermediate application layer to add this value for display, but didn't necessarily care about query time (maybe from direct from SQL reporting mechanism for instance), your approach may be preferred.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Probably be better off to use yours as a subquery and replace the null Status then to do the union. Optimizer would probably handle that better.